# Changing angular route not able to work anymore

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I've changed my (previously working) angular website route from ui.route to ngRoute as there was a view minor issues.

It's now rendered my website useless.  The links don't work and it's full of errors.  I've spent hours trying to fix it.

I keep getting errors:

**controllers.js**:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
angular.js:38

**Uncaught Error:** [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=financeApp&p1=Error…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A350)

I would like to be able to change between views via the navbar.

The only changes I have made was the CDN address, the script.js file and the controllers.js file.

controllers.js:

```
financeApp.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
}
)

.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
 })

.controller('candidatesCtrl', function($scope) {
 })


.controller('clientsCtrl', function($scope) {
 })

.controller('aboutusCtrl', function($scope) {
 })

.controller('trainingCtrl', function($scope) {
 })

financeApp.controller('contactusCtrl', function($scope) {
 })

financeApp.controller('joinusCtrl', function($scope) {
 })
```

and script.js

```
var financeApp = angular.module('financeApp', ['ngRoute','rangeSlider','ui.bootstrap'])


 financeApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
                .when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                    controller: 'homeCtrl'
                }).
                when('/candidates', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/candidates.html',
                    controller: 'candidatesCtrl'
                }).
                    when('/clients', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/clients.html',
                    controller: 'clientsCtrl'
                }).
                     when('/aboutus', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/aboutus.html',
                    controller: 'aboutusCtrl'
                }).
                   when('/training', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/training.html',
                    controller: 'trainingCtrl'
                }).
                    when('/contactus', {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/contactus.html',
                    controller: 'contactusCtrl'
                }).
                   when('/upload', {
                    templateUrl: '/partials/contactform.php',
                    controller: 'joinusCtrl'
                }).


                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        });
```

Comment: You included the ng-route js file in your HTML?

Comment: what is the correct error? It's truncated in your question.. and how do your links look like? .. do you have html5mode enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to double check

**1st**
You are most probably missing or havent included files for one of the three dependencies ngRoute,rangeSliderui.bootstrap

**2nd:** Make sure you have included the script files in this order

```
<script src="your_path/angular.js"></script>
<script src='angular-route.js'></script>
<script src='ui-bootstrap.js'></script>
<script src='range-slider.js'></script>
<script src="your_path/script.js"></script>
<script src="your_path/controllers.js"></script>
```

**3rd:**

You are mixing chain pattern and referencing with variable

make sure you have `financeApp` in front of controller registration

```
financeApp.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

At line 6 in controller.js there is a semi-colon - remove it. Infact they are everywhere, remove all of them.

Line 5 through 9 form a code like this.

```
.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
 });.controller('candidatesCtrl', function($scope) {
 });
```

Do you see the . after simi-colon above? That's the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I've removed the semi colons but it says I have an injector module problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the application in front of all your .controller statements:

```
financeApp.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
 });

financeApp.controller('candidatesCtrl', function($scope) {
 });

financeApp.controller('clientsCtrl', function($scope) {
 });

financeApp.controller('aboutusCtrl', function($scope) {
 });

financeApp.controller('trainingCtrl', function($scope) {
 });
```

And you need to remove the extra enter in:

```
financeApp.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```